# invoking facebook api(php) using java program hosted in google app engine

Tags: java, php, facebook, google-app-engine

I created a Facebook API using PHP and MySQL and hosted it on a domain.  Now I would like to host it on Google App Engine, however, Google App Engine does not support PHP.  I would like to learn how to write a Java application that can invoke Facebook's API through HTTP and host the Java application on Google App Engine.

If you have any advice or links on how I can accomplish this, it would be a big help.

Comment: You "created a facebook API"? Do you mean you created a facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

FYI GAE does support PHP Now: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/introduction